# Sorting currency in VB.NET

Tags: sql, vb.net, datagridview, currency, columnsorting

I'm having difficulty addressing the issue of a currency sorting problem within our in-house software package. The software in question is written using VB.NET and the values are contained within DataGridView, the relevant code is:
[SQLReader.Read() Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6Y3D.png)

and the result is: [Value Column incorrectly sorted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UudIW.png)

There are more examples further down the column where values with commas inside them don't appear to sort correctly as well. How do I get them to sort?

Comment: Please include the code inline in the question.

Comment: Your currency/value strings are sorted correctly - by alphabet of course. Does your database really contain a sting like '$10,000.99'? That should be two fields, one for the numeric value and one for the currency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see your code is converting numeric currency values to a string and then displaying the string in the `DataGridView` - that's your problem: this means the DataGridView will be performing lexicographic-ordering on the strings instead of numerical ordering (i.e. `"21"` is ordered after `"123"` because `'2' > '1'`.

I don't know what the definition of `m_DataRow` is, but it smells like you're using untyped DataSets, or perhaps a crudely created typed-DataSet but without any meaningful column names and types.

Unfortunately because your DataGridView looks to be bound to this `m_dataRow` object you're stuck unless you can recreate it correctly (e.g. with actual column names and types). However if you're using untyped DataSets then just change your code to stop formatting currency values to string but instead provide the raw `Decimal` value directly, and then use DataGridView's own column formatting to specify the "C" (for currency) format string.