# Sorting Currency Column VB.NET in RadGridView

Tags: vb.net, sorting, currency, radgridview, columnsorting

I'm trying to sort the currency column in a radgridview using Custom Sorting.

The only other question I could find that's related was this one: [Sorting currency in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33034331/sorting-currency-in-vb-net) but it doesn't provide a solution.

I tried using the Telerik example https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/controls/gridview/sorting/custom-sorting which I have implemented below.

```
Private Sub CustomSort(sender As Object, e As GridViewCustomSortingEventArgs)
    Dim row1 As Decimal
    Dim row2 As Decimal

    If e.Row1.Cells("Pickable").Value.ToString = "" Then
        row1 = 0
    Else
        row1 = Convert.ToDecimal(e.Row1.Cells("Pickable").Value.ToString.Substring(1))
    End If
    If e.Row2.Cells("Pickable").Value.ToString = "" Then
        row2 = 0
    Else
        row2 = Convert.ToDecimal(e.Row2.Cells("Pickable").Value.ToString.Substring(1))
    End If

    If row1 > row2 Then
        e.SortResult = 1
    ElseIf row1 < row2 Then
        e.SortResult = -1
    Else
        e.SortResult = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

It provides me with the following result when I sort:

[image: Results]

But then it won't allow me to sort descending.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Using answer suggested below - I have implemented a Click Event.
[image: click event]

*SOLUTION*
[image: solution]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your cells actually contains `Strings`, try this:

```vb
Dim value1 As Decimal
Dim value2 As Decimal

Decimal.TryParse(CStr(e.Row1.Cells("Pickable").Value), NumberStyles.Currency, Nothing, value1)
Decimal.TryParse(CStr(e.Row2.Cells("Pickable").Value), NumberStyles.Currency, Nothing, value2)

e.SortResult = value1.CompareTo(value2)
```

If the blank cells are actually NULL rather than empty then you can take advantage of the fact that `DBNull.ToString` returns an empty `String`:

```vb
Decimal.TryParse(e.Row1.Cells("Pickable").Value.ToString(), NumberStyles.Currency, Nothing, value1)
Decimal.TryParse(e.Row2.Cells("Pickable").Value.ToString(), NumberStyles.Currency, Nothing, value2)
```

With regards to sorting in descending order, I don't know how that control indicates the sort direction but, if you're doing custom sorting, I'm guessing that it's up to you to remember it yourself. In that case, you could use a field to specify the current direction:

```vb
Private isDescending As Boolean = True
```

You can then just toggle that on each sort, e.g. in a `Button.Click` event handler before calling a `Sort` method:

```vb
isDescending = Not isDescending
```

You can then set the comparison result based on that direction:

```vb
Dim value1 As Decimal
Dim value2 As Decimal

Decimal.TryParse(e.Row1.Cells("Pickable").Value.ToString(), NumberStyles.Currency, Nothing, value1)
Decimal.TryParse(e.Row2.Cells("Pickable").Value.ToString(), NumberStyles.Currency, Nothing, value2)

e.SortResult = If(isDescending, value2.CompareTo(value1), value1.CompareTo(value2))
```

Comment: Hi yes it's a string column. It's throwing a 'Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'String' is not valid.' error, how would I handle this for the null values regarding your example?

Comment: I added the .ToString() and it's running now with no errors but all the results are scrambled, see my post I'll post a screenshot

Comment: Ah, I realise why that's happening. I was toggling the direction as though the event was raised once per sort, but that's not the case. It would be raised as many times as are required to perform enough comparisons to sort the data. That means that you would need to toggle the `isDirection` field once for each sort. I don't know exactly how you would do that because I don't know how you're initiating the sort. If, for instance, you are clicking a `Button` and calling a `Sort` method, you would toggle the field before calling `Sort`.

Comment: The sort is activated using a single mouse click on the radgridview column header, I have tried to implement a click event on the radgrid and I have posted the results in my answer

Comment: Using your answer combined with telerik's I have achieved the result I am looking for. Thanks for your help!